# swift ios adding search bar to picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a picker view that shows up once you press a button.
Now I wonder if its possible to add a search bar to the picker view? Just like in a table view.

I have tried to work with UIToolbar but I cant get it to work, so is this even possible/allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to put the search bar inside the UIPicker you can't;
but you have the option to use third party pickers, take a search in:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com

otherwise, if you want to add the search control outside the picker, yes you can.
just change the picker selected row when the user edit the text on the search bar, this guide can be useful:
http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet var pkrview: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var lbl1: UILabel!

var state = ["Gujarat","Bhihar","U.P.","Maharastra","J&K"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return state.count 
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return state[row]
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let fv = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController")as!WebViewController

    fv.str = state[row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(fv, animated: true)

    lbl1.text = state[row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UITextfield to have both search and bottom results. I will recommend you to use this Cocoapods. It is just easy to use and integrate this [link](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField)